# Export Zotero library into Google Scholar

Tags: google-scholar, reference-managers

I am trying to find a way to synch the collection of papers I have in Zotero to my Google Scholar library.
Ideally the synch would be bidirectional, but I undestand that is probably not feasible at the moment, so I am ok with anything that allows me to export my Zotero library inside Google Scholar.

I have seen a ton of guides on how to do the opposite, from Scholar to Zotero, but I cannot find anything on how to transfer from Zotero to Scholar.

Could anyone help me with this please? Going through all the papers one by one would be extremely panful.

Comment: Does Google scholar have any instructions on how to import? Have you asked or contacted them?

Comment: @SolarMike I have looked at the [docs](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/help.html#library) and couldn't find any way to do that. I am not really sure what you mean by contacted them, if you have any way to contact the Scholar team I'd be happy to do it.

Comment: Interesting. I've recently published a software library for automating the export of Google Scholar citations to Zotero. If you're willing to go on GitHub and open a feature request for this then I'll add it to the library. https://github.com/hack-r/pyserpZotero