# How to view similar articles from a Zotero collection?

Tags: citations, literature-search, reference-managers

Recently I moved from Mendeley to Zotero. In Mendeley I liked that once in a while they sent me article recommendations based on my library. I would like to know how I could manage to achieve something similar with my Zotero library / collection.

Similar questions:
[Tool that suggests references based on a given bibliography](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/114931/tool-that-suggests-references-based-on-a-given-bibliography/115384#115384), [Export Zotero library into Google Scholar](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/144526/export-zotero-library-into-google-scholar)

Answer (score 3):

I am fairly certain that Zotero does not have such a feature and has no plans to include it. Here is an older discussion on the topic: https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/71940/mendeley-suggestions.

However, if this feature is very useful to you, then I suggest the following workaround: use Zotero from here on as your reference manager, but keep Mendeley on the side (free no storage plan) for its recommendations service. The key to this solution is enabling Zotero integration from within Mendeley. I hope this option is still active, but here are the instructions on how to activate it: https://sites.google.com/a/mendeley.com/mendeley-training/home/learn/organize/switching-from/zotero

> 1. Open up Mendeley Desktop and go to Tools > Options (or Mendeley Desktop > Preferences if you're on a Mac)
> 2. Select the Zotero / CiteULike tab. From here, just enable the checkbox for Zotero integration.
> 3. Mendeley Desktop will attempt to automatically locate your Zotero database. You can choose to use an alternate Zotero database if
>    desired.
> 4. Once you've clicked Apply, all of your existing documents from Zotero
>    will be imported into Mendeley Desktop, and any future items you add
>    to Zotero should find their way into Mendeley Desktop automatically.

So, once you have set this up, you should be able to use Zotero as normal, and then your Mendeley account should still keep on sending you recommendations as before.

By the way, I am a long-time Zotero user. I have tried Mendeley, but have never found any compelling reason to switch. Since I do not have Mendeley installed to test the solution I proposed, please confirm in a comment if it works for you.

Comment: Nice work around! Though I'm having some problems to automatically synchronize my Zotero library to Mendeley. Instead, because I have in Zotero the files attached as links in a folder, I will import the files in Mendeley with the option of `Watched folder`.